# image background onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to create a function where by a button is clicked and the background image is selected for a div. Here is what I have started below but it does not seem to work can anyone point out where Im going wrong... :)

```
<style type="text/css">
#txt{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: solid #000;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function backg1(){
        var test = new string ();
        test = document.getElementById('txt');
        test.style.backgroundImage="url('cloud.jpg')";
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="txt">
<input type="button" value="BG1" onclick="backg1()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in your error console? By the way, the `new string()` is of no use, especially if you immediately overwrite it with a DOMNode from `getElementById()`

Comment: I think you'll need to set the width & height  of `div#txt` to the size of the image. (also position relative)

Comment: what worked ? setting the width & height?  I'll put it in as an answer below and you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: CSS Assigning values to the height AND width

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Let alone the fact that it should be capital `new String()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `<div>` originally contains nothing but the button input, it has no size outside the boundaries of that button. You will need to set an explicit width and height (along with `position: relative`) to see the background.

I would recommend setting them to the same dimensions as your image.

```
/* in the CSS */
#txt{
    /* use the width, height of your image */
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid #000;
}
```

Or if you need to set them dynamically:

```
function backg1() {
    test = document.getElementById('txt');
    test.style.backgroundImage="url('cloud.jpg')";

    // <div>  needs a width & height for the background image to be visible outside the 
    // bounds of the one element contained in the div.
    test.style.width = "400px";
    test.style.height = "250px";
    test.style.position = "relative";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript error at this line. 
var test = new string ();

You can make it like var test = new String(); Then it should work.

Moreover, i observed that you are creating string object and then you are overriding with DOM object. Not sure why it so like that. You can just create a variable like var test;